# Jquery: Wrap each <LI> with an <a href="#"> that links to the text of the <LI> it's wrapping around, but replaces the spaces with hyphens (-)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('h2').each(function() {
    $('UL.chapters_list').append($('<li/>', {text: $(this).text()}))
});
```

This code grabs all of the `<H2>` tags on the page, then copies each of them to their own `<LI>` inside of `<UL class="chapters_list">`, so essentially it creates a list of all the `<H2>` tags.

I need to wrap each `<LI>` tag that it creates, with an anchor link, this link should have the text of the `<h2>` that it grabbed, but replacing the spaces in the `<h2>` with hyphens `'-'`

So let's say my script sees 2 `<H2>` tags on the page, so it grabs the texts of those `<H2>` tags and copies them to:

```
<UL class="chapters_list">
<LI>title number one</LI>
<LI>and number two</LI>
</UL>
```

I need it to now wrap each of those

tags with an anchor link, the anchor link will be the text of the LI(or the H2 it just grabbed) but with hyphens (-) replacing spaces.

so the above will turn into:

```
<UL class="chapters_list">
    <a href="#title-number-one">
        <LI>title number one</LI>
    </a>
    <a href="#and-number-two">
        <LI>and number two</LI>
    </a>
</UL>
```

Can anyone help? it shouldn't be too hard, with the code i've provided, thank-YOU.

Comment: Should be the other way round: anchors in `li`. Doing it this way won't invalidate your HTML. To get the anchor to fill up the entire space of the `li` use `display: block` on the anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are about to generate invalid HTML. The links must be inside the list elements.

This works:

```
$('h2').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('<li/>')
        .append($('<a />', {text: text, href:'#'+text.replace(/\s/g, '-')}))
        .appendTo('ul.chapters_list');
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/mL2HV/

Comment: Hey would you know how to also erase all commas with what you did in the .replace() part of the code? so, make all spaces into hyphens, and then ALSO erase all commas.
 thank you!

Comment: @android.nick: That would be `replace(/,/g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
$('ul.chapters_list li').each(function() { 
    jLi = $(this); 
    jLi.wrap($("<a>").attr('href','#' + jLi.text().replace(/\s/g,'-') )) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Having anything other than an `<li>` as a direct child of a `<ul>` is non-compliant HTML.  Different browsers may handle that differently, and in my experience, IE in particular will not be happy.  you should reverse the order, creating a structure like so:

```
<ul class="chapters_list">
    <li>
       <a href="#title-number-one">title number one</a
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#and-number-two">and number two</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You'll want to do your js like this:

```
$(function() {
    var myUL = $('<ul></ul>');
    $('h2').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var href = txt.replace(/ /g, '-');
        myUL.append('<li><a href="#' + href + '">' + txt + '</a></li>');
    });
    $('body').append(myUL);
});
```

This will create a ul, the iterate over all you `<h2>`'s, creating an `<li>` for each one.  It uses a simple regex `/ /` to replace the spaces in the text of the `<h2>` with hyphens.

Here's a working demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/n3RMh/1/

Comment: This will only substitute the first "space". You need to add the *global* modifier to replace all: `/ /g`.

Comment: @Felix Kling - You are correct, thanks for pointing that out.  I have modified my answer to fix that error.